# Server side solution to convert PDF to SWF?

Tags: pdf, flash, server-side

I've found some tools that can convert PDF to SWF, but I'm hoping to find something or even a library to be able to be able to incorporate this on the server to be able to store the SWF in a database.

Comment: Is your intent to create unique SWF files for each PDF? An alternative may be to convert PDFs to a generic vector file, such as SVG, which can be dynamically loaded through Flash.

Comment: Well my thought was just do use something like FlexPaper for display, but I wanted users to be able to just upload PDF's and just worry about conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried SWFTOOLS? On Debian/Unbuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install swftools
pdf2swf filename.pdf
```

http://wiki.swftools.org/index.php/Examples#pdf2swf
They have a Windows version, and the source so you can compile it on other Linux flavors.